# OpenCV TextReconitionModel failed with CTC-prefix-beam-search

Tags: opencv, text-recognition

usage:
OpenCV 4.5.3-dev

I followed this example: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/dnn/scene_text_spotting.cpp
It is use:

- for the detection model: DB_TD500_resnet50.onnx
- for the recognition model : crnn_cs.onnx
- for the vocabulary: alphabet_94.txt
- the decode type is set to: "CTC-prefix-beam-search"

These settings received the following error:

```
OpenCV(4.5.3-dev) C:\DevTools\opencv\modules\dnn\src\model.cpp:745: error: (-2:Unspecified error)     in function 'class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl cv::dnn::TextRecognitionModel_Impl::ctcPrefixBeamSearchDecode(const class cv::Mat &)'
>  (expected: 'prediction.size[2] == (int)vocabulary.size() + 1'), where
>     'prediction.size[2]' is 96
> must be equal to
>     '(int)vocabulary.size() + 1' is 95
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one empty line at the end of the vocabulary or push_back one more item in the vocabulary vector.
I don't know if is only a workaround or a real solution...